# Make stores listen to change in another store

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have a Flux app with 2 stores: `ACCOUNT-STORE` and `CLIENT-STORE`.

Currently the app lets the user filter for a specific country and the whole filter logic has been implemented into each store (since both account data and client data have to be filtered by country). So both store: 
1- listen to a `SELECT_COUNTRY` action triggered by a component
2- create a filter function that will keep only the selected country
3- apply that function to their data

Since the number of filters will grow, I was wondering if it would be possible to move steps 1 and 2 into a third store that would just manage the filters: `FILTER-STORE`.

Now `FILTER-STORE` listen to `SELECT_COUNTRY` and create the filter function, but I cannot find the best practices to make `ACCOUNT-STORE` and `CLIENT-STORE` listen and react to change in `FILTER-STORE`.

In the AppDispatcher.register of `FILTER-STORE`, I tried to call another action after creating the filter function:

```
switch (action.actionType) {
    case AppConstants.SELECT_ACCOUNT:
        updateAccountFilter(action.data);
        AppActions.stfil_selectAccount(
            FilterStore.getAccountFilter()
        );
        break;
```

My plan was to make `ACCOUNT-STORE` and `CLIENT-STORE` listen to this action and use its payload. But I fall on the error message:

`Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.`

So maybe there is another way? Is it possible to make `ACCOUNT-STORE` and `CLIENT-STORE` listen to `FILTER-STORE` just like my components listen to stores?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest setting up global events as shown here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events and then in your onComponentDidMount function ascribe to those global events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are trying to do goes against Flux unidirectional data flow architecture, explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content). Stores shouldn't emit changes for themselves to listen, the should only listen to actions from components and emit changes to components as well.

If you want to DRY your filter logic, you should create a corresponding FilterActionCreator that will handle dispatching SELECT_ACCOUNT and other actions. You can read more about it in this extensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630611/should-flux-stores-or-actions-or-both-touch-external-services).

This will keep your logic DRY and your flow safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I did not think of action because I thought it was better to leave them as "clean" as possible. But you are right that it  works well in this case.